# How to access a shared directory with Virtualbox OSE

Tags: file-sharing, virtualbox

I would like to share data between a VirtualBox OSE guest OS and the host. This location should be also writable by either of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Virtualbox gui; select the guest you wish to have the shared directory and select "Settings".  In the dialog box, select the "Shared Folders" tab (on the left).  Click on the "+" button on the right to create a new location (of an existing directory on the host).  On the next guest boot, the location will be available to the guest OS (depending on how it accesses drives).  As long as the underlying filesystem is writable to the Virtualbox guest, then it will be writable by both guest and host.

Comment: Note that the guest needs the Virtualbox Guest Additions libraries installed - e.g. in Windows, this is accomplished through the "Install Guest Additions" menu item, Ubuntu guests can install the virtualbox-guest and virtualbox-guest-x11 packages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the other way around. Then set up a network share in the guest, and connect to in from the host. Note: Use a host only network interface.